# jquery script not working: trying to insert a link after the existing link

Tags: jquery

i have an rss link. sample.rss. i open it in firefox and opens well.

in that page i try:

```
$('h3>a>span').each(function () {
  $(this).parent().after("<p>Test</p>")
})
```

it works

but when i try

```
$("h3>a>span").each(function(){
   url1 = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q="'+this.textContent+'"'
   console.log(url1)
  $(this).parent().after('<p></p><a href="'+ url1 +'">other</a>')
})
```

it says SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

console.log shows the url1 variable properly.

whats the problem.

again the below works

```
$("h3>a>span").each(function(){
   url1 = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q="'+this.textContent+'"'
   console.log(url1)
  $(this).parent().after('<p></p><a href="#">other</a>')
})
```

Comment: url1 = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+this.textContent; - make it simpler...quotes are problem....

Comment: The problem is, I think, the quotes (as nevermind mentions); but on an unrelated note I'd suggest not creating a paragraph inside of a heading element; the heading elements, as the name itself implies, are for headings, not content. Also with questions involving JavaScript and HTML we really need to see (a representative sample of) both in order to reduce your problem; please: add a sample of your "[mcve]" code so that we can help.

Comment: try this code on example site http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_freevideo.rss

Comment: No; the relevant (again: *minimal*) code needs to be included in your question. Otherwise, should that 'example site' be moved in future the question, and its solutions, become meaningless to others in future that are experiencing the same, or similar, problem. Questions need to be self-contained on this site; please, take a look at the "*[ask],*" as well as the previously-linked "*[MCVE],*" guidelines to understand *why*.

Comment: Ok. I was just trying like that. Nothing much specific.

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi Why you don't write `;` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the followings:

```
$("h3>a>span").each(function() {
   url1 = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=' + this.textContent;
   console.log(url1);
  $(this).parent().after('<p></p><a href="'+ url1 +'">other</a>');
})
```

Comment: whats the difference

Comment: Made the var ('url1') simple and put necessary semicolons;

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/69Ljogo0/1/

I tidied up the code for you as well. You were almost correct in your first approach:

```
$(".item h3 a").each(function(){
    var url1 = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=' + this.textContent;
    console.log(url1);
    $(this).after('<p><a href="'+ url1 +'">other<a></p>');
});
```

Content from http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_freevideo.rss as you provided.

Comment: You can also replace the default link connected to the title. ie: $(this).attr('src',url1);

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to understand what is creating the problem. I was thinking there may be some syntax errors.

I finally found the main issue in this code.

i wanted the below to work which gives error:

```
$("h3>a>span").each(function(){
   url1 = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q="'+this.textContent+'"'
   console.log(url1)
  $(this).parent().after('<p></p><a href="'+ url1 +'">other</a>')
})
```

the problem is with the `"`.  and also if the `this.textContent` contains spaces or any other things it will give error.

so i used escape() function and changed the code to following

```
$("h3>a>span").each(function(){
       url1 = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q='+ escape('"'+this.textContent+'"')
       console.log(url1)
      $(this).parent().after('<p></p><a href="'+ url1 +'">other</a>')
    })
```

i tried this on http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_freevideo.rss and it worked.

if i escape the entire url, then when i click google says error page not found. so i escape only the part of the url

Note: url1 should also not contain & instead it should be replaced with %26

Its about the url special characters which are not accepted when run by javascript.